# Illegal offset type again

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, warnings

Here is another Illegal offset type again, but can't find asnwer!?

```
$GLOBALS['q']   = array();
$init_query[]   = array();


if (!empty($init_query)){
    foreach($init_query as $key => $bit){
        $GLOBALS['q'][$bit] = ($key !== (count($init_query)-1)) ? $init_query[$key + 1] : null;
    }
}
```

It's;

```
$GLOBALS['q'][$bit] = ($key !== (count($init_query)-1)) ? $init_query[$key + 1] : null;
```

there is the problem. $init_query is a single dimensional array.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

`$init_query[]   = array();` results in `array(array());` You then loop over it and do:
`$GLOBALS['q'][$bit]` which is `$GLOBALS['q'][array()]` which is an illegal offset. Offsets can only be scalar values like numbers and strings.

> $init_query is a single dimensional array.

It's **not**.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$init_query = array();
```

instead of

```
$init_query[] = array();
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what Benjamin's trying to do, but if he sets $init_query = array(), then the next check if not empty will always be false.

Comment: You are absolutely right.